# Use setter to dispatch event when object property is changed

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to use a setter/getter to dispatch an event every time an object property is changed? By changed, **I mean member added, deleted or updated.**

Below is a non-working example of what I am trying to achieve. Each time a member is added to `instance._dataStore`, `instance` should trigger an Event.

```
var EventDispatcherObject = require("EventDispatcherObject");

var instance = new EventDispatcherObject();

//This is a non-working attempt to use setter to dispatch event
Object.defineProperty(instance, "_dataStore", {
          get : function() {
                    return this_dataStore;
          },
          set : function(data) {
                    this._dataStore[data] = data;
                    this.dispatchEvent("_dataStoreChanged");
          }
});


var data = [{id: "A", data: "abc"}, {id: "B", data: "def"}, {id: "C", data: "ghi"}];

for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
    instance._dataStore[data[i].id] = data[i];
}

//should return:
console.log(instance._dataStore);
>>> {
      A : {id: "A", data: "abc"}, 
      B : {id: "B", data: "def"}, 
      C : {id: "C", data: "ghi"}
    }
console.log(instance._dataStore[A]);
>>> {id: "A", data "abc"}
```

Actually this non-working example return that error:

```
InternalError: too much recursion: return this._dataStore;
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What about your example is not working (besides the invalid syntax due to the missing end bracket for the getter, and the fact that there is no such (built-in) class named `EventDispatcherObject`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your setter is defined for the `_dataStore` property, not for *properties of the `_dataStore` property*. So it will only be triggered if you assign `_dataStore`.

You should investigate using a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) instead; that lets you hook into *any* setter, whereas a normal setter is only for *specific* properties.

```
this._backingData = {};
this._dataStore = new Proxy(this._backingData, {
  set(target, prop, value, receiver) {
    target[prop] = value;
    this.dispatchEvent("_dataStoreChanged");        
  }
});
```

Comment: It seems `instance._dataStore[prop]` is not populated at the moment the event is dispatched inside the Proxy, so I cant access its properties in the event listener function. Is that normal?

Comment: Make sure you set the value in `target` before dispatching the event.